# Не переведено сообщение о защите вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не переведено сообщение о защите вопроса, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.**

[еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532007/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-input)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже что-то сбрасывает перевод

Comment: Odd; the page uses the right syntax, and translations do exist - I'm investigating. (
Странный; страница использует правильный синтаксис , и переводы действительно существуют - я расследую . - via google translate)