# Непереведённая надпись о защите вопроса в неавторизованном режиме

Tags: дефект, локализация, защищённые-вопросы

Надпись о защите вопроса выводится на русском языке, если ты авторизован:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если не авторизован, то выводится на английском (возможно, выбирается по системной локали):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильное ли это поведение, ведь остальные элементы страниц переведены в обоих режимах?

Скриншоты из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908373/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-pimpl-c) вопроса.

Comment: Возможно, связан с [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3101/Не-переведено-сообщение-о-защите-вопроса) вопросом

Comment: "*возможно, выбирается по системной локали*" - нет, это три строки без русского перевода: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Thank%20you%20for%20your Вы можете сами предложить перевод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строки разные используются для авторизованного и нет. А перевод слетел из-за небольшого изменения исходной (английской) строки.

[Добавил перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/421) (и для смежных множественных форм):

> Благодарим вас за интерес, проявленный к этому вопросу. 
>   Так как он собрал большое количество ответов низкого качества и спама, который пришлось удалить, для публикации ответов теперь необходимо иметь $rep$ баллов репутации на сайте (бонус за ассоциацию учётных записей не учитывается).
>   $br$$br$
>   Может быть, вы захотите ответить на один из неотвеченных вопросов?

Будет на сайте после синхронизации с движком.